# Read JSON object in object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to read the below highlighted value:

[image]

by reading

> str.hourly[2]["rain.1h"]

but getting Undefined error. What is the correct way to access that value?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `str.hourly[2].rain["1h"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply: `str.hourly[2]["rain"]["1h"]`; Since `rain` is an object has `1h` property